# Is it easier to reverse engineer or break a Delphi program if the exe file was compiled with debug compiler settings?

Tags: delphi, debugging, pascal

if I accidentally forget to switch to release configuration before releasing my program, does it matter in terms of it being easier to decompile or reverse engineer my code?

For example if I accidentally use the following debug compiler options:

```
1. Compiling:
    - StackFrames = True

2.  Debugging
    - Debug information = Debug information
    - Local Symbols = True
    - Symbol Reference info = Reference Info

3.  Linking
    - Map File = Detailed
```

I have read help and from what  I can tell it doesn't make much difference unless the map file is also somehow released with the binary file, so I wonder how much a difference it makes if someone has the map file?

Comment: Well, with a map file, the user has the actual function names and memory offsets. Without it, the user has to make up names for whatever functions their chosen disassemble discovers.

Comment: I always build for release with full debug info, detailed map file etc. This is needed to construct stack traces for bug reports. But I don't ship the map file to the client, or any debug info.

Comment: What Delphi version are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's clarify one by one the options you've mentioned:

- **[Compiling > Stack frames](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Stack_frames_(Delphi))**: Stack frames are only needed for debugging (and maybe to generate stack traces for error reporting, as mentioned by @DavidHeffernan in the comments). Even if you enable it in release builds, that won't be very helpful for reverse engineering.
- **[Debugging > Debug information](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Debug_information_(Delphi))**: With this option set, the debug information is compiled inside the DCUs to help debugging inside the IDE. It's not linked into the exe, so it's obvious that it won't help reverse engineering.
- **[Debugging > Local symbols](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Local_symbol_information_(Delphi))**: With this option set, the compiler includes basic symbol information in the debug info, but again, it only helps when debugging on the IDE and it's not linked into the final exe.
- **[Debugging > Symbol reference info > Reference info](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Symbol_declaration_and_cross-reference_information_(Delphi))**: Additionally to the previous option, this one includes detailed information about *unit-local* symbols (variables, constants, classes and so forth) to aid in debugging. They're also not linked into the final exe.
- **[Linking > Map file > Detailed](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Detailed-Segments_Map_File)**: With this option set, the linker will create a detailed `.map` file containing all the information (type, name, address, size, etc.) about program's symbols, so, of course it would be helpful for reverse engineering **IF** you distribute this file along with your exe (as stated by @RemyLebeau in the comments).

There's also the option to generate remote debug symbols, as pointed by @dummzeuch:

- **[Linker > Include remote debug symbols](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/devcommon/remotedebugprepfiles_xml.html)**: This option tells the linker to generate a `.rsm` file, it's the Delphi equivalent of Microsoft's `.pdb` [Program Database Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1(vs.71).aspx). If you distribute this file, you could be on real trouble, because one could easily debug your application, visualize symbols, functions and procedures, single-step your code and so on.

Also, I think it's important to say that `.map` files are not equivalent to `.pdb` files. For Delphi Win32, `.rsm` is the equivalent. I have not worked with Delphi for years, but as far as I can remember, no Delphi Win32 version can generate `.pdb` files. Only Delphi for .NET can.

That said, let's go back to your questions:

> I wonder how much a difference it makes if someone has the map file?

Reverse engineering would be much easier having a `.map` file. I've seen some tools in the past that can even convert a `.map` file to a `.dbg` file for use with a debugger.

> Is it easier to reverse engineer or break a Delphi program if the exe file was compiled with debug compiler settings?

Well, one important (and maybe the most noticeable) characteristic of Debug builds is the bigger exe size. That's mainly because in the Debug configuration the compiler disables a number of code optimizations in order to facilitate code debugging. There's also a lot of *debug-conditional* code (eg.: inside `{$IFDEF DEBUG}` directives) that gets linked into the exe.

As a side effect, the code generated by a Debug build is much easier to reverse engineer because it's simpler to understand.

Comment: There is also the option to include remote debug symbols in the executable (on the Linker options page). That might actually help in reverse engineering.

Comment: @dummzeuch I forgot about that one. It's now included. Thanks.

Comment: Oops, I mentioned the wrong option: I actually meant the "Include TD32 debug info" in Delphi 2007 (no Idea whether it is still available in later versions), which is actually added to the exe file.

Comment: @dummzeuch, seems like that option doesn't exist in recent versions. Anyway, you previous comment was helpful.

Comment: In newer versions it is simply called "debug information" in the linker tab iirc. (which is something else from the same in the compiling tab)